# Scope of transactions and prepared statements

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wonder how transactions and prepared statements are scoped. With scoped, I mean if they are bound to a specific connection or environment in wich they were created.

More specifically:

- Can a prepared statement be reused on a connection other the one it was created on?
- Can a prepared statement be used inside a transaction if it was created outside of that transaction and vice versa?
- Is a transaction bound to the connection it was created on?

Limited to one client of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can a prepared statement be reused on a connection other the one it was created on?

No, it's session (connection) specific.

The terms "session" and "connection" are currently interchangeable in PostgreSQL, as there's no way to save a session and restore it on a later connection.

> Can a prepared statement be used inside a transaction if it was created outside of that transaction and vice versa?

Yes. Prepared statements are session-level, not transaction-level. There's no `PREPARE LOCAL` for a transaction-level prepared statement, like `SET LOCAL` for transaction-local variables.

You can use the `DISCARD` command to forget prepared statements, or `DEALLOCATE` to forget one particular prepared statement. This is used heavily in transaction/connection poolers like PgBouncer.

(Of course, all involved transactions must be on the same session, as prepared statements are session-specific).

> Is a transaction bound to the connection it was created on?

Yes. Transactions are properties of a session. You can't suspend a transaction in one session and restore it in another. It'd be quite handy, but is extremely impractical given PostgreSQL's process-based architecture.

A tool like PgBouncer or PgPool-II lets you abstract connections by a layer of indirection that offers some more flexibility.

Comment: Well, I guess 2) is not correct, since 1) conflicts. Assume that every transaction/prepared statement is created on a random connection. 2) would only work if the statement was created on the same connection as the transaction, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ErikAigner Transaction yes, session no. (2) refers to *transactions*.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean with "transaction yes, session no"

Comment: @ErikAigner You can re-use prepared statements across multiple transactions on the same session. You cannot reuse them across different sessions (connections). Hence my answer to (2) and why it does not conflict with (1).

Comment: Yes, and I said every query may use a different connection, because I get them from a connection pool. So it would only work if I happen to get the same connection from the pool where the PS was created on.

Comment: @ErikAigner Some connection pools can pre-prepare a bunch of statements when a new connection is allocated from the pool. It'd be nice if PostgreSQL supported something like `PREPARE IF NOT EXISTS` but it doesn't. You can use `pg_catalog.pg_prepared_statements` to see if statements are already prepared, but the extra round trip makes using prepared statements less useful in the first place.